# Символы не отображаются правильно

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

Код на вид вроде-бы правильный, но все же не работает. Как мне сделать, чтобы в `product.out` отображалось так же как и в `product.in`?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct product
{
    string name;
    long double price;
    int rating;
   string description;
    int available;
    int sold;

}v[1000];
int main()
{ int i,n;
 ifstream cin("product.in");
 ofstream cout("product.out");
  cin >>n;
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        getline(cin, v[i].name);
      cin >>v[i].price;
      cin >> v[i].rating;
    getline (cin ,v[i].description);
      cin >> v[i].available;
      cin >> v[i].sold;


for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    cout << v[i].name << endl;
    cout << v[i].price << endl;
        cout << v[i].rating << endl;
        cout << v[i].description << endl;
        cout << v[i].available << endl;
        cout << v[i].sold;
    return 0;
}
```

Вот что я хочу чтобы мне отображалось

`Product.in`

```
3
Skytech Archangel
999.99
4.5
Gaming Computer PC Desktop – Ryzen 5 3600 3.6GHz, GTX 1660 6G, 500GB SSD, 8GB DDR4 3000MHz
5
2
The Book of Eli
14.99
4.8
A lone warrior (Denzel Washington) wanders the post-apocalyptic desert that was once America
12
4
ACER LCD Display
130.95
4.5
Screen Size: 21.5 Inches; Resolution: Full HD; Display Technology: LCD; Brand: Acer; Series: V7
16
12
```

А вот что мне отображается

`product.out`

```
Skytech Archangel
999.99
4.5
0

0
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл косяки!

1. Думаю, вам стоит обрамить фигурными скобками все цикли.
2. Сделайте по два `getline'a`
3. Вот так с циклом - `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`
4. Ваш cin-файл перекрывает настоящий `std::cin`. Допишыте везде `std::cin` или удалите тот `fstream`
5. Не забываем очищать ресурсы после файлов! `cout.close();`